# SP2019 - Load Balancing

Tags: 2019, roles, load-balancing, minrole

I have SP2019 set up in MinRole topology ( x2 App w/search and x2 Web w/ DistCache ).

What's the best way to load balance ? I am thinking of using the standard Windows Server NLB feature.

Do I only need to load balance the x2 Web Front End servers ? or do I also need to load balance the apps servers too ? My understanding is no, as that is handled within MinRole itself.

Other aside question; if my x2 Web w/dist cache servers are acting as the web servers, why do all of the app pools and sites appear on all servers within IIS including the app w/search servers ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

WNLB isn't fit for production usage.

I would look at appliances or services to do this. Cisco, F5, KEMP all have appliances while there are a bunch of free services including HAProxy, nginx (which you can use along with CARP under OpenBSD or keepalived under Linux), among others.

HAProxy in TCP mode + keepalived on Linux is what I personally use.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to load balance the “WFE”s.  The rest of the roles are load balanced internally by SharePoint and very intelligently (such as “prefer local” where the server won’t make a call to a service application on another server if itself hosts that SA).